Как создать шаблон
Как создать шаблон принимающий переменное количество параметров,
плюс к этому у параметров тоже переменное количество параметров.
struct S {
    int x;
    std::string s;
    S(int x, std::string s): x(x),s(s) {}
}

int main(){
list<S> l;

l.push_many(( 1,"a" ), ( 2, "b" ), ( 3, "c" ));

}



Не очень понятен вопрос, зачем нужен шаблон. Но то что вы хотите сделать в приведенном коде решается через список инициализации. И подобные конструкторы нет смысла писать.

std::list<S> l = {{1,"a"}, {2,"b"}, {3,"c"}}; - чем плохо?

Хотелось бы сделать такой метод в своём list,который бы и конструировал S и добавлял его в лист

@ДенисАхунов для этого нужно каким-то образом "разделить" сет аргументов. Если предпологать общий случай (любая неизвестная заранее структура) , то напрямую так сделать конечно не получится (нет никаких "разделителей" внутри аргументов функции). Если структуры только агрегированные то можно почитать число полей в структуре и грубо говоря понимать только N%K==0 шаблонных параметров (где N - общее число, K - число полей в структуре). И естественно можно написать что-то вроде своего билдер-паттерна и конструировать до бесконечности (примерно то что предлагают в ответе ниже)

Тут пригодится библиотека boost.assign
#include <boost/assign/list_inserter.hpp>

#include <list>
#include <string>

struct
Item
{
    int m_x;
    ::std::string m_s;
    Item(int x, ::std::string s): m_x{x}, m_s{s} {}
};

int
main()
{
    ::std::list<Item> items{};
    ::boost::assign::push_back(items)(1, "a")(2, "b")(3, "c");
    return 0;
}

online compiler

Я сам реализую свой list. И мне хотелось бы написать свою шаблонную функцию которая принимала бы переменное количество переменных с переменным количеством переменных.

как раз таки тоже самое что и делают в этой библиотеке
